# Do the Prime Number Theorem and/or Riemann Hypothesis predict a limit on the accuracy of this formula for $\gamma$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, riemann-hypothesis, euler-mascheroni-constant, mobius-function

This question is related to the following formula for Euler's constant $\gamma$ where $A$ is Glaisher's constant.

**(1)** $\quad\gamma=12\,\log(A)-\frac{\pi^2}{6}\sum\limits_{n=1}^N\frac{\mu(n)}{n^2}\,\log\left(\frac{2\,\pi}{n}\right),\quad N\to\infty$

---

The discrete plot in the following figure illustrates the error in formula (1) above as a function of $N$. The red evaluation points illustrate the error in formula (1) above where the Mertens function $M(N)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^N\mu(n)$ evaluates to zero.

---

[image: Error in Formula (1) as a function of N]

**Figure (1)**: Error in Formula (1) as a function of $N$

---

**Question**: Do the Prime Number Theorem and/or Riemann Hypothesis predict a limit on the accuracy of formula (1) for $\gamma$ as a function of $N$?

---

### 3/30/2019 Update:

---

Since $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\mu(n)}{n^2}=\frac{6}{\pi^2}$, formula (1) above can be simplified as follows.

**(2)** $\quad\gamma=12\,\log(A)-\log(2\,\pi)+\frac{\pi^2}{6}\sum\limits_{n=1}^N\frac{\mu(n)}{n^2}\,\log(n),\quad N\to\infty$

---

Formulas (1) and (2) above can be simplified further as follows.

**(3)** $\quad\gamma =12\,\log(A)-\log(2\,\pi)+\frac{6}{\pi^2}\,\zeta'(2)$

Answer (score 3):

Yes and this is supposedly obvious. If $$\sum_{n=1}^N \mu(n) n^{-2} \log(2\pi/n) = C+O(N^a)$$ then $$\log(2\pi)/\zeta(s+2) + \zeta'(s+2)/\zeta(s+2)^2= s \int_1^\infty (\sum_{2 \le n \le x} \mu(n) n^{-2} \log(2\pi/n)) x^{-s-1}dx$$ is holomorphic for $\Re(s) > ...$

The converse is a matter of summation by parts to make $\sum_{n=1}^N \mu(n)$ appear as well as the converse theorems about its growth assuming the RH

Comment: Before asking this question I briefly explored $f(x)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^x\frac{\mu(n)}{n^2}\,\log\left(\frac{2\,\pi}{n}\right)$ and $F(s)=s\int\limits_0^{\infty }f(x)x^{-s-1}\,dx=\sum\limits_{n=1}^N\frac{\mu(n)}{n^{s+2}}\,\log\left(\frac{2\,\pi}{n}\right),\, N\to\infty$. I'm not sure the Dirichlet transform of $\frac{\mu(n)}{n^2}\,\log\left(\frac{2\,\pi}{n}\right)$ is $\frac{\log(2\,\pi)}{\zeta(s+2)}+\frac{\zeta'(s+2)}{\zeta(s+2)^2}$ because if it were as I'd expect $F(s)$ to converge to this function for $\Re(s)>-1$as $N\to\infty$ which it doesn't seem to do.

Comment: ??? ${}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Shouldn't  
"$\log(2\pi)/\zeta(s+2) + \zeta'(s+2)/\zeta(s+2)^2= s \int_1^\infty (\sum_{2 \le n \le x} \mu(n) n^{-2} \log(2\pi/n)) x^{-s-1}dx$ is holomorphic for $\Re(s) > ...$"  
be  
"$\log(2\pi)/\zeta(s+2) - \zeta'(s+2)/\zeta(s+2)^2= s \int_0^\infty (\sum_{1 \le n \le x} \mu(n) n^{-2} \log(2\pi/n)) x^{-s-1}dx$ is holomorphic for $\Re(s) > ...$"  
(where ... is $-3/2$ assuming the Riemann Hypothesis)?

Comment: I don't understand how using summation by parts to separate out $M(x)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^x\mu(n)$ helps derive a bound for $f(x)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^x\frac{\mu(n)}{n^2}\,\log\left(\frac{2\,\pi}{n}\right)$ as the bound of $M(x)$ increases as $x$ increases whereas the bound of $f(x)$ decreases as $x$ increases. The second Chebyshev function $\psi(x)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^x\Lambda(n)$ is similar to $M(x)$ in that its bound increases as $x$ increases. Are there well-known arithmetic functions 
that have bounds predicted by the RH that decrease as $x$ increases similar to $f(x)$?

Comment: @StevenClark See the end of the [other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3154481/276986). Then it reduces to $M(x) = O(x^a)$ implies $\sum_n M(x) (n^{-s}-(n+1)^{-s}) = \sum_n M(x) O(sn^{-s-1})$ converges for $\Re(s) > a$ (for the details look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_series#Abscissa_of_convergence )

Comment: Based on your answer to my other question, I concluded $F(s)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\mu(n)}{n^2}\,\log\left(\frac{2\,\pi}{n}\right)\,n^{-s}$ converges to $\frac{\log (2 \pi )}{\zeta (s+2)}-\frac{\zeta '(s+2)}{\zeta (s+2)^2}$ for $\Re(s)>-\frac{3}{2}$ (assuming the RH).

Comment: I'm not sure how to interpret the Wikipedia article with respect to an RH bound on $f(x)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^x\frac{\mu(n)}{n^2}\,\log\left(\frac{2\,\pi}{n}\right)$ since the Wikipedia article assumes the abscissa of convergence of $F(s)$ is $>0$. Also, I find the Wikipedia article somewhat confusing as it seems to refer to $s_o$ both as a complex variable and a real constant.

Comment: Assuming the RH $\sum\limits_{n=1}^N\frac{\mu(n)}{n^2}\,\log\left(\frac{2\,\pi}{n}\right) = L+ O(N^{-3/2+\epsilon})$ and is not $= L+ O(N^{-3/2-\epsilon})$ so the abscissa of convergence is $\lim \sup_{N \to \infty} \frac{\ln |\sum_{n=1}^N\frac{\mu(n)}{n^2}\,\log(\frac{2\,\pi}{n}) - L|}{\ln N} \in  [-3/2-\epsilon,-3/2+\epsilon]$ thus is $=-3/2$. Nowhere $s_0$ is a real constant, see again the definition of $O(N^{s_0})$

Comment: Wikipedia is supposed to be the general result, the only assumption is that the Dirichlet series converges somewhere (thus for $\Re(s)$ large enough)

Comment: The Wikipedia reference starts off with "Assume that $\textstyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n n^{-s_0} $ converges for some $\textstyle s_0 \in \mathbb{C}, \operatorname{Re}(s_0) > 0$" which is why I questioned its applicability. The second bullet seems closely related to your recent comments but indicates if $L = \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n $ converges, then $L=0$. This is inconsistent with $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\mu(n)}{n^2}\,\log\left(\frac{2\,\pi}{n}\right)=\frac{6\,(12\,\log(A)-\gamma)}{\pi^2}=1.46379...$ and the more well known example $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\mu(n)}{n}\,\log(n)=-1$.

Comment: Please work seriously on wiki's proof. It doesn't say $L=0$. It is saying for negative abscissa of convergence with need to substract the value of $L=\sum_n a_n$ from $A(N)$.

Comment: Wikipedia defines $O(g(x))$ and $o(g(x))$ where $g(x)$ is a real-valued function (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation). What definition are you referring to with respect to $O(N^{s_0})$ where $s_0\in\mathbb{C}$?